# concatenated 2 data frames and values are NaN in the last one, but resetting the index gets rid of the date

Tags: concatenation

I have 2 data frames that I concatenated with df_new= pd.concat([df_stocks,df_crypto], axis=1, join="inner"). The original df_crypto shows correct values in the data frame when I print it, but it has Nan as values once I concatenate it to df_stocks.  I tried using .reset_index(drop=True) for both data frames when concatenating them, and that did allow me to see the data (and not just Nan). However, resetting the index eliminates the dates, and the "inner" join method of only showing data when crypto and stocks both are open (not weekends) is eliminated. When I didn't reset the index, the inner join did show the data only for the days when both assets traded. Is there any way to keep the dates as the index for the inner join method but reset the index so I can see the concatenated dataframes values?

Answer (score 0):

Might need to know more about the layout of your dataframes to give a complete answer. What are their `df.info()`?

Also try the `on` parameter on the pandas *join* function.

```
df_new= df_stocks.join(df_crypto, on="date_col", how="inner")
```

I find that joining on indexes in pandas can be unpredictable.

PS: "inner" will only keep data that is present on both dataframes. If you want different behavior try: "left", "right" or "outer".

Comment: the .info() function shows float64 for the data type of every element and 234 non-null count for each column/element. I did want to keep the data that was only present in both dataframe and my reason for using inner.  For example, a stock did not trade on 5/1/22 but crypto did, so my df_crypto has a row of values for that date but df_stocks doesn't.  When joining the dataframes together, I didn't want a row to show up on 5/1/22 since data was not present in both dataframes.    I couldnt find any documentation on the on parameter for concat, and it returned an unexpected keyword argument

Comment: For the on parameter in concat checkout this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas-dataframe-join). Might depend on your pandas version.

Comment: Correction, I was talking about df.join and not df.concat. I edited my answer to show this

Comment: thanks for the response and correction. Unfortunately, i am still getting NaN for all the crypto data when I both join or concat that df to the other one. The original crypto dataframe has good values though, so I will continue to play around with it.  I thought maybe my date being a string instead of datetime in the crypto df might be causing an issue, but that didnt fix it.